# Stata: searching for specific conditions in different variables

Tags: search, panel, stata

I have data that look like as follows.

```
Time    Patient Doctor  Fee charged in $
Jul-08      A       3       36
Jul-08      B       3       40
Jul-08      A       2       39
Jul-08      A       1       40
Jul-08      B       1       35
Jul-08      C       3       40
Jul-08      D       3       44
Jul-08      E       1       45
Jul-08      E       3       41
Jul-08      F       1       45
Jul-08      F       3       44
Jul-08      G       1       39
Jul-08      H       2       37
Jul-08      H       1       35
Jul-08      H       2       41
```

For example, `Patient` A visited `Doctor` 3 who charged `Fee` 36 dollars. I want code to give  the minimum `Fee` for a given patient and what happens if a `Patient` switches to another `Doctor`.

This is a sample data set for the illustration of my question and I want to do it for almost 30,000 observations.

Comment: I worked at your presentation and hope that I didn't distort your question. It's probably in your best interests to get help from a friend with better command of English, as busy people just skip questions too difficult to read.

Comment: I answered your question, but it is off-topic here as "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results." See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and give your attempted code in future questions. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: Title is very vague. Suggest as a specific title "Stata: identifying minimum values within groups of observations".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt help infact I have revised my question. I would take care of the English issue next time. As I posed my first question on this forum I was unaware of the full requirement although I gave a cursory look on the guidance of asking the question.Any how thanks a lot for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the help for `egen` and consider the results of calculations like

```
egen min1 = min(Fee), by(Patient Doctor) 
egen min2 = min(Fee), by(Patient)
```